# Converting DSL jobs into a pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to migrate old fashioned Jenkins DSL jobs (in Groovy) to the new descriptive pipeline form.

Since I'm very new to the pipeline and I could not find any answer to my noob problem, I'll firstly describe my scenario here:

1. Supposing I have 3 DSL jobs, one to build and save the artifact generated in a repository like Artifactory, another to tag the master branch and the last one is used to deploy to prod. All jobs use the same Git repository.
2. The building job is usually run many times during development. It can be triggered manually or as a response to events in the Git repo, e.g. merge requests and pushes.
3. For simplicity, let's assume the tagging job only needs to tag the master branch in the repo. This will only be run once in a while, manually, when we are pretty sure the master branch will go to prod.
4. Artifact gets deployed using a third job, also manually.

So here are my questions:

- As I understand we can only have one file per branch in the repo, so how can I configure such a setup using a pipeline defined in only one Jenkinsfile?
- How can I manually trigger the tagging job only (meaning compile/test/generate the artifact without uploading and then if everything tests ok, tag the version)?
- In this situation, will it be easier for me if I just implement the building job in the pipeline and keep the others as DSL scripts?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: You could do it with pipeline, by turning the individual jobs into conditionalized stages (see `when` statement). These could check boolean parameters that default to `false` and could be set to `true` when manually triggering the pipeline.

Comment: Firstly, many thanks for your suggestion.
I thought about that one, it seems a practical way to deal with this situation. I'll try to find an example on how to implement this (meaning identifying how a pipeline is manually triggered and changing parameters accordingly).